# Using Mayavi and Mlab to plot "bubbles"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mayavi

Currently, I am attempting to plot some "bubble" like shapes in a 3D space using Mayavi/Mlab. These bubbles are represented by a numpy array of shape `(840,1100,30)` where the parameters represent `(x,y,z)` and the value at any `x,y,z` is either 1 or 0. The array can be thought of as a collection of Voxels that are either on or off. I try to plot this data with the following commands:

```
mlab.contour3d(finalVolume)
mlab.show()
```

But the plot is coming out in 2 dimensions instead of in 3 dimensions. I have looked at the documentation but am having trouble understanding. If anyone could provide some help or a push in the right direction, then I would be very appreciative!
Thanks!

Comment: The reason is looks like it's 2D is likely due to the scaling.  `mayavi` will treat each voxel as though it's 1x1x1 by default.  That means that your overall array will be ~30 times as wide/long as it is tall.  Therefore, it looks 2D, even though it isn't.

Comment: I was so sure that I made a code mistake that I simply didn't think of this as a solution. However, you were totally right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use volume rendering to accomplish this.  This can be accomplished using:

```
mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s), vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
```

You will need to adjust the opacity transfer function using vmin and vmax to make an appropriate image.  Examples on volume rendering can be found at: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html